# Uploading picture to Parse for to a specific ID

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, parse-platform

I am creating an app, where the user will get an image delivered to an UIImageview. I am using Parse to fetch the image. I am using this code:

```
-(void)updateImage
{

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Image"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:@"<<PARSE--ID>>" This is an automatic message!We are very sorry that we have to tell you, the number you are texting with has blocked you! If the reason was spam we can not do anything! If you still want to contact +436653212523 you can Call! Have a Nice Day!:^(PFObject *imageObject, NSError *error) {

    if (imageObject) {
        PFFile *imageFile = imageObject[@"image"];
        [imageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
            if (data) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                if (image) {
                    self.imageView.image = image;
                }
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error fetching image file: %@", error);
            }
        }];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error fetching object: %@", error);
    }
}]; }
```

Now i need to be able to upload a picture to this id. How do i do that? i have all of the code for choosing the image. Thanks in advance for the help.
Julian

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by 'upload a picture to this id'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved a bit differently.

I did it like that:

```
-(IBAction)UploadImage:(id)sender {
    // Convert to JPEG with 50% quality
    NSData* data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(ImageView.image, 0.5f);
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:@"Image.jpg" data:data];

    [imageFile saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // The image has now been uploaded to Parse. Associate it with a new object
            PFObject* newPhotoObject = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"PhotoObject"];
            [newPhotoObject setObject:imageFile forKey:@"image"];

            [newPhotoObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"Saved");

                }
                else{
                    // Error
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
     }
```

Now it works seamlessly.